# JavaScript: простая библиотека для рисования на Canvas

Tags: javascript

Без физики, просто фигуры рисовать, двигать и менять их размеры.
Гуглил, ничего внятного не нашел. Box2djs - перебор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/)